# Why $invalid, $valid, $dirty don't work in my AngularJS project in Visual Studio?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a simple registration form as part of the training, it is necessary to use AngularJS. There are three fields on the form. If the fields are not filled, then the "Submit" button is inactive. If everything is filled out and everything is ok, then alert 'our form is amazing' should appear. The project was created in Visual Studio. But there is no reaction from the form, except for the messages "Fill this field." The button is always active, but the alert does not appear. 
When I added the sample code to the question, I saw that everything works correctly here. But in my VS it seems AngularJS part is ignored. I tried to download similar projects and run them in VS - everything was ok. Tell me please what is the problem?

```js
var saveUserApp = angular.module('saveUserApp', []);
saveUserApp.controller('saveUserController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.save = function () {
        if ($scope.form.$valid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Save user</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="saveUserApp" ng-controller="saveUserController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-3">
                <h2>Save user</h2>
                <form name="form" ng-submit="save()">
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.login.$dirty && form.login.$error.required }">
                        <label for="login">Login</label>
                        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" ng-model="login" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.firstName.$dirty && form.firstName.$error.required }">
                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.lastName.$dirty && form.lastName.$error.required }">
                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ng-model="lastName" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, answer is toput your script tag after the one that references Angular

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/saveUser.js"></script>
```